# Hersetin's example on the group of $1-1$ mappings on $S_3$

Tags: group-theory

I have started reading Herstein's *Topics in Algebra.* On pp.30 while discussing the group of all 1-1 mappings on a set that has three elements, they state the following:

> Consider the elements (mappings) $e$, $\phi$, $\psi$, $\psi^2$, $\phi \cdot \psi$, $\psi \cdot \phi$; these are all distinct and are in $G$, which has only 6 elements. Thus this list enumerates all the elements of $G$.

The specific constructions of the mappings $\psi$ and $\phi$ are given in the book. How has the author been able to claim that the number of distinct mappings on the set are six? Is it generally the case that on a finite set of $n$ elements, there can be at most $n!$ distinct mappings? If show, can someone prove this claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of bijections on a set of $n$ elements is exactly $n!$. This is because there are $n$ options for $f(1)$, after this there are $n-1$ options for $f(2)$ etc.